# Python: nested list iteration

Tags: python

My list is a nested list like this: 
`[[3, 0, 5, 2, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4], etc.`

function overunder returns tuple like this: `(1,2,3,4,5,6)`

`worksheet2.write` writes results in excel file

I need every function result (tuple) to be written on the new row in excel file

So I came up with the following code

```
for item in list:
    ou = overunder(item)
    i = 0
    ii = []
    s = sum(ii)
    while i < len(ou):
        worksheet2.write(s + 2, i + 2, ou[i])
        i += 1
    ii.append(1)
```

It seems working fine, the only problem I have to increment `s` with each for  loop. 
But strangely enough `ii` doesn't get appended.

What may be wrong?

Comment: It is not very clear what is your problem... You append to `ii` only once after the loop. Does `s` supposed to be the row count? Why do you calculate it like that? Why not just a loop?

Comment: "I have to increment s with each while loop": What does this mean?

Comment: I need first while loop go with s+2 = 2, second while loop go with s+2 = 3 etc.

Comment: Then why aren't you doing `s += 1` just like with `i`? Why the weird list `sum`?

Comment: or maybe there is another more simple solution

Comment: sorry, it seems i need s to be incremented for the for loop. still don't know how to do that

Comment: I need the following: first while(2, i+2...  second while(3, i+2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `s` and `ii` get their values re-initialized **on each `for` loop**. You want to move `ii = []` to be defined **before** the loop. But anyway, that is a weird way of maintaining `s` with `sum`ming the `ii` list. Your code could be simplified by using the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```py
for row, item in enumerate(lst):
    ou = overunder(item)
    for col, element in enumerate(ou):
        worksheet2.write(row + 2, col + 2, element)
```

---

By the way, you didn't mention what library you are using to write to the excel. Using [openpyxl](/questions/tagged/openpyxl) you can take advantage of the [`append`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.append) method to write a whole line at once and greatly simplify your code:

```py
for item in lst:
    worksheet2.append(('', '') + overunder(item))
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I'm using xlsxwriter, probably not the best choice as well. Thanks  for you solution and suggestion, appreciated a lot!

Comment: and yes, I just had to put ii = [ ] before the for loop, that would solve the problem too

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try this:

```
for i in range(6):
    print(i)
```

This will print numbers from zero to five.

I can't understand your problem, but you are initializing your list with `ii = [ ]`, this will delete the contents of your list. After this you `sum([ ])`

Hope it is helpful!